# How to grab GET parameters in ASP.NET web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm going from the ASP.NET Web API template to get rolling on building an API. I need to figure out a way to take the GET parameters and apply them to my code so for example:

I would like to query my DB for names like "TOYOTA" by entering:

`http://localhost:64360/api/values?name=TOYOTA`

For now, here's the code that I have to work with:

```
' GET api/values
Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Return New String() {"value1"}
End Function
```

For the moment, this URI will return a single JSON object that just says:

```
"value"
```

But for the sake of figuring out  how to input GET parameters into the VB code above,

How could I make the block of code above return whatever is inputed as `?name=AUDI` so that instead of just getting `"value"` I would get AUDI, TOYOTA, or whatever the GET parameter with `name` is?

Comment: Do a simple google search on this [HttpRequest.QueryString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx) show a little more effort

Comment: Not sure what is relation between WebAPI and your question... Normally you just let ASP.Net bind parameters to your WebAPI / MVC Controller actions and almost never need to look at raw query string...

Comment: @DJKRAZE `HttpRequest.QueryString Property` has little reference to GET. Coming from the Linux world I would have never guessed to search that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebAPI paramenters use almost the same approach as MVC,

So just change input parameters like this:

```
Public Function GetValues(name As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api. It doesn't look to me as though you are really using Web API, but instead are trying to build, by hand, a lot of the stuff that Web API provides. In particular, look at the model binders as those will really give you a lot of flexibility, especially in terms of flexibility of input formats (i.e. automatic acceptance and decoding of XML, JSON or GET parameters).

You should be naming actions on your controller that match the verbs, e.g. GET, POST, etc.

I think you need to do some more research into the Web API.